# Algorithm to find smallest representative sample of two-variable dataset?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Suppose I have a list of times that I can measure the temperature and pressure of a gas (for example).  I know what the temperature and pressure will be at each time.  I want to measure a uniform range of temperatures and pressures, with the fewest amount of measurements.  Assume these variables are independent.

As a bonus, I want to avoid bunching, so that I'm making my set of measurements over the given interval of time as evenly as possible.  This is optional.

This doesn't have to be particularly rigorous, so a lazy, naive, heuristic, quick-and-dirty, good-enough approach is fine, and even preferable.

Any insight on how I should think of this, or what to Google?

Comment: Have you considered selecting `m` of your `n` times uniformly at random and measuring at those times? The expected outcome of this seems to align with your criteria.

Comment: Just to be clear... your purpose here is to "lie with statistics" via biased sampling?

Comment: @Patrick87 my main concern there is that the number of desired tests is small.  Like, I'm hoping to sample over the full range of both variables with as few as, say, ten measurements, so it would hopefully be a different temperature and a different pressure for each one.  I think this would work well if I were shooting for 50 or 100 measurements, but I'm not sure it would work randomly without some kind of constraint, just because `m` is so small.  However, I can give it a go!

Comment: @MattTimmermans, not at all.  My purpose is to minimize measurements.  They're secondary to the main purpose of the project, for calibration purposes, and the tests are expensive to do and must be fit into a very full schedule.  Does that clarify?